# Google Sheets activate a cell within a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a loop that does what I want, but I would like to set an active cell in each sheet so I don't have to click it each time as I cycle through.

I've tried two ways that seem to make sense, but they both only work on the last sheet in the loop:-

```
function setDraft() {

//msg box to confirm relevant sheets are hidden, thus excluded from code
  var response = Browser.msgBox("SET AS DRAFT","Have you hidden sheets you don't want marked as draft?", Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
  if(response=="no")
    return;
  else if(response=="cancel")
    return;
  else

//loop and code for Visible sheets  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (var s in allsheets){
  var sheet=allsheets[s]
  var date = sheet.getRange('I1')

  if (sheet.isSheetHidden()!= true) {   
//sheet.setActiveRange(date);
  sheet.setActiveSelection(date);
  sheet.getRange('I5').setValue('DRAFT');
       }    
    }
}
```

Can anyone please let me know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you missed to put the statements after the last else inside a block. Have you tried to use the debugging tool in the Google Apps Script Editor?

Answer (score 0):

Using `for...in` in JS can lead to problems (more on that [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500531/2278429)). Second, try using the built in UI class through the `SpreadsheetApp` class rather than the `Browser` buttons.

```js
function setDraft() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var allsheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  //msg box to confirm relevant sheets are hidden, thus excluded from code
  var response = ui.alert("SET AS DRAFT","Have you hidden sheets you don't want marked as draft?", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if(response == ui.Button.NO) {
    return;
  } else {
    for (var s=0; s<allsheets.length; s++){
      var sheet=allsheets[s]
      var date = sheet.getRange('I1')

      if (sheet.isSheetHidden()!= true) {   
        sheet.setActiveSelection(date);
        sheet.getRange('I5').setValue('DRAFT');
      }    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either...
Where are the curly braces missing, ?

after "if(response=="no")", but then I can't work out where they close?

Comment: I updated my answer to include the curly braces. Also, consider using the UI class rather than Browser.

Comment: I'm getting allsheets is not defined, so I tried to define with:

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();

but that still isn't leaving 'I7' as the active cell in each sheet either?

Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: I added the variable (my fault). It activates I7 when the script runs and changes the values. It doesn't necessarily leave the cell selected when it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sheet.activate()` or `range.activate()` methods. Use [sheet method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#activate()) if you only care to go to a specific sheet, but if you want the select a specific cell then use it with [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate()). I have not tested with range, however, I know that if you use `sheet.activate()` then you will be brought to that sheet.